# Word for someone who wins a given round of a tournament

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that means "*the winner of a given round of a tournament*" that is not ambiguous with the winner of the entire tournament. Does anyone know of such a word?

Comment: Tourney formats are so varied that it's generally specified.  Like "won their pool" or "stage winner."  There are, though, better terms for the overall winner, such as *champion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some sports, where there is an elimination tournament, for example basketball, the game between the two undefeated teams are called the "finals", and the two teams competing in the finals are called the "finalists'. The contests won by the finalists were the "semi finals", and the teams playing in these games are called the semi-finalists. And the games played to determine who would compete in the semi-final games are (in this scheme) called the "quarter-finals", and the teams playing in these games are the "quarterfinalists". There are not names in common use for the teams playing in the quarter final games. In Golf, where the tournament is a bit differently laid out, these terms are not use. My understanding that in Golf, There is a large group of players on the first two days of the tournament, of whom half of those players will "qualify" to advance to the final two days of the tournament. Those who do not play well enough to play on the final two days of the tournament did not "make the cut", and those who did, are "qualifiers".

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if most people would pay close enough attention to the subtle distinction but I would strongly suggest the word **Victor**.

The definition found in [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Dictionary [1828]](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/) seems to indicate that  the word [Victor](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=victor&use1828=on) can refer to a person who has won by to some limited degree in a larger context, by defeating a specific opponent. The first sense indicates that this meaning is primarily geared towards battle. However I can not help but notice the use of the adjective "private" just before "combat or contest" as a single round between contestants would be.

The more modern Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary simply defines Victor as:

> [":A person who defeats an enemy or opponent."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victor)

Oxford Dictionaries Online defines Victor as:

> " [A person who defeats an enemy or opponent in a battle, game, or other competition.](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/victor)"

All of the cited definitions seem to indicate that in the primary sense is special emphasis is on the defeat of the opposition, rather than just the act of winning itself. This seems especially well fit for a single round in a tournament, since that is the only time you could defeat an opponent. Oddly Victorious does not seem to carry the same connotations.

However either of the cited Webster's dictionaries also accept the word Victor as a direct replacement for the word Winner, meaning that specifying in what exact sense the person is The Victor may still be necessary. This is particularly advisable particularly since like I mentioned earlier, I doubt most people care for the subtle distinctions and implications between words.  This would especially be the case if you pluralized it as Victors or referred to somebody as a Victor in the past tense, since The Champion has to be considered a Victor in some sense by necessity: After-all, he did reign victorious in all of his matches. With the added specification Winner does work.Regardless of that, contextually declaring a person a Victor or even a Winner immediately after the match, probably would make it fairly clear that you did not mean to designate them as the premature champion of the tournament.

Also if you are going to be a contestant of a tournament, it may be within the jurisdiction of its organizers to redefine how words apply to the event as a part of its rules. It is especially at their discretion that any special title is conferred so if you plan to be a contestant, you should probably consult the rulebook or ask an authority like a referee. If you are one of the organizers, then I would still highly recommend using Victor.